# The function of distance between two points with time

Tags: geometry

Consider I have two points *p* and *q*, and a line segment *l: y=mx+c* (actually the enpoints of the segment are given). There is a circle with center *q* which is growing with time *t*, i.e. the radius *r = k.t* where *k* is some constant. Consider *z(t)* be a point(s) of intersection between the line segment and the growing circle.

What would be the shape of the graph between *d(p, z(t))* and *t*, where *d(p, z(t))* is the distance between point *p* and *z(t)* . we take the intersection point *z(t)* which is far from *p*.

[image: the picture shows growing circle with time and intersection point *z(t)* with the line segment. thin line is the distance *d(p, z(t))*.]

I can find the intersection points z(t) at any time t because the radius and the center are known. Then I simply calculate the distance between p and z(t). I get the intuition that the graph will be similar to the dark line shown in picture below. Is it possible that the curve can go above the dashed line.

[image]

Comment: its a more complex problem. this is just a part of that. I want to know the increase in distance between p and z(t) with time t.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. What have you tried?

Comment: DO you mean my approach to this?

Comment: Yes @CODError..

Comment: I have put some extra details. I couldnt think of a proper approach. I am stuck with the details I have provided. Now, my main concern is to prove the the dark line curve could not go above dashed line shown in the example graph. I am actually doing a linear interpolation, and I dont want the actual distance value to have higher value that the linearly interpolated value at any time t

Comment: "By definition the curve will always be below the dashed line". How can I prove this? I want to linearly interpolate between two endpoints of the curve. I want to prove that the curve won't go above the line. What do you mean "by definition".

Comment: you are saying things so vaguely- "a definition of what". I guess you can at least point me to an article where I can read about this. Or tell me about the "the definition". If I had known the axiom, I would not have put the question here.

Comment: @JossieCalderon think of the problem for some time and then comment. You are just commenting vaguely and deleting it.

Comment: @CODError If you take the point which is further away from $P$  then the claim is not true. The curve goes above the dashed line i.e. the distance function $d(p,z(t))$ is concave down. It turns to concave up later on. The shorter distance on the other hand behaves the way you want it. But this is not a proof. I only checked one specific case.

Comment: @Lozenges how did you check it? *d(p,z(t))* is the distance of point p from further point z(t) in case we have two intersection points. Can you show me the proof? or explain to me how it failed to an specific case?

Answer (score 1):

Use coordinate geometry. The line L is along the $x$-axis, the point $P(0,p)$ is on the $y$-axis, $Q(a,b)$ is the second point and the radius $r= kt$. The equation of the circle
$$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=k^2t^2$$
Put $y=0$ and solve for $x$ to get
$$z(t)=a+\sqrt{k^2t^2-b^2}$$ 
and the distance $d$ is given by
$$d^2=p^2+\left(a+\sqrt{k^2t^2-b^2}\right)^2$$
Special case: $p=5, a=4, b=3, k=1$

$$d=\sqrt{25+\left(4+\sqrt{t^2-9}\right)^2}$$

This curve is above the dotted line for $3\leq  t \leq  10$